# choose which query to run among multiple queries within a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query,which consists of 3 queries.
On the basis of the result of one query,I want to run either of the other 2 queries.

```
SELECT 

CASE type


    WHEN 'H'
     THEN (select count(*) from tableN where hid = 228)

    when 'S'
     THEN (  select cid,cname from tableC where cid = (select hid from tableN where sid = 228)  )


END

FROM tableC WHERE cid=228;
```

But since **one of the queries returns only 1 column i.e. count(*)** ,whereas **the other query returns 2 columns i.e. cid and cname** ,I am getting the following error :

**Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

How can I modify my query so that-----

when type is 'H',the following query runs:

```
select count(*) from tableN where hid = 228
```

and when type is 'S',the following query runs:

```
select cid,cname from tableC where cid = (select hid from tableN where sid = 228)
```

Comment: The columns in the result set for a SQL query are fixed.  Keep this in mind and edit your question provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I don't see what possible value you get out of wrapping different queries with another query and then choosing between them with a `type` variable.  It only makes things difficult for you.  Maybe you should reconsider your approach here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider few things before solving this problem.

1. A subquery in SELECT part of main query has to return single row, single column always.
2. A query output should always give consistent no. of columns as output.

ex:

Incorrect: `select col1, (select col2, col3 from...) , col 4 from table 1`

Coreect :  `select col1, (select col2 from..), (select col3 from..), col4 from table 1`

Considering these 2 constraints, solution for your question could be

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS col1, null AS col2, 'H' AS colType from tableN
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CID AS col1, CNAME AS col2, 'S' AS colType FROM tableC where .....
  )
where colType = :input_type
```

Now depending on value of `input_type` result from query 1 is selected or query 2 is selected.
Note:

- the query 1 will have a dummy column to match no of rows.
- input_type is 'H' or 'S' based which is variable being supplied by you
- Query 2 is incomplete as I wanted to show structure, not to spend time on full details.
- Further, this query has risk of executing both query even if you wanted results of only 1 query
- Suggestion is to move your logic of selecting which query to execute to either a procedure block or application layer. Its not a good design to use SQL to decide which query to execute on run time. application layer logic is right place for that (assuming there is some other program which calls this query, you should consider having this logic there)